# How to define an ACL policy applied globally for all models in a LoopbackJS application

Tags: loopbackjs, acl, strongloop

Is there a way to define a global ACL which would apply to all models included in the Loopback application?
Ideally, this globally defined ACL could be overriden by an ACL defined in a model JSON file.

Does Loopback supports something like this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `loopback-cli` tool:

```
$ lb acl
? Select the model to apply the ACL entry to: (all existing models)
? Select the ACL scope: All methods and properties
? Select the access type: All (match all types)
? Select the role All users
? Select the permission to apply Explicitly deny access
```

it will update all your models acl's, and then you can continue with adding new ACL rules.

Otherwise, if you need to do it programmatically, you could add this code somewhere to your boot scripts: 
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/3318

Just replace the `Model` in the example with the array of your models - assuming that the `app` is `server/server.js`, then in `app.models` you have all the models defined.